# Access data from one Datagrid to another

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am developing a User Interface to view the student details from a student Database. 
I have three datagrids in my application as follows:

The first datagrid at the left is for selecting the Student from the list and the other two must display the information about the selected student.

the *Student Info* datagrid is dependent on *Select a Student* datagrid and the *Personal Information datagrid* is dependent on *Student Info* datagrid. 
I have done the database connectivity to populate the list of students in the Select a Student datagrid, but I dont know how to proceed further. So far I have understood that I should create a `DataGridView.CellClick` Event.

Could anybody suggest me to proceed further.

[image: User Interface for Student database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the `ItemsSource` of the *Personal Information* datagrid to the `SelectedItem` of the *Student Info* datagrid and the ItemsSource of the *Student Info* datagrid to the `SelectedItem` of the *Select a Student* datagrid.

That way the *Student Info* datagrid will automatically update as you select a student and the *Student Info* datagrid will automatically update as you select an item in the *Student Info* datagrid.

The Binding:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=StudentDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.StudentInfo}"
```

Replace the ElementName and the Path with the name of your datagrids and the correct property.

Comment: Thank u Eirik, I got a good idea from your suggestion. but what do u mean in the second sentence.. ?
"That way the Student Info datagrid will automatically update as you select a student and the Student Info datagrid will automatically update as you select an item in the Student Info datagrid"

Comment: @Buba1947 When you select a student in your first datagrid, the Student Info datagrid will be updated with the correct values since it's bound to the `SelectedItem` of the first datagrid. Same goes for the Personal Information datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

Hi If you following MVVM then its better you bind SelectedItem /SelectedValue of DataGrid to get the SelectedItem instead of SelectionChanged event.I hope this will help.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedStudent.FamilyName}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedStudent.PhoneNumber}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        Students.Add(new Student()
        {
            Name = "James",
            FamilyName = "mangol",
            PhoneNumber = "01234 111111"
        });
        Students.Add(new Student()
        {
            Name = "Bob",
            FamilyName = "angol",
            PhoneNumber = "01234 222222"
        });
        Students.Add(new Student()
        {
            Name = "Emma",
            FamilyName = "pangol",
            PhoneNumber = "01234 333333"
        });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    private Student selectedStudent;
    public Student SelectedStudent
    {
        get { return selectedStudent; }
        set { selectedStudent = value; Notify("SelectedStudent"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

}
public class Student:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; Notify("Name"); }
    }



    private string familyname;

    public string FamilyName
    {
        get { return familyname; }
        set { familyname = value;Notify("FamilyName"); }
    }



    private string phonenumber;

    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get { return phonenumber; }
        set { phonenumber = value; Notify("PhoneNumber"); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

The above example demonstrates how to use **SelectedItem** using Binding.This is not the exact solution of your problem but this will give you idea how to use SelectedItem.I have shown for ListBox it works same for DataGrid.

Comment: Yes, I am following the MVVM pattern to populate the details in the datagrid. could you explain more please.

Comment: Thanks indeed. I will have a look =)

Answer (score 0):

On selection of a student, you should get the ID of the selected record. And from there, you can load the details based on the ID of the record.